# That's a "fair" question

Tags: meaning

I have a question about "fair".

Boss: Why you left your previous workplace?
Interviewer: That's a "fair" question...

What does "fair" mean? Does it mean good, reasonable, agreeable, or others?
Does it mean that the interviewer think this is a good question?
Or, does the interviewer think this question should be known by the boss?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you must mean *interviewee* (= the person being interviewed), not *interviewer* (= the person doing the interviewing).

Anyway: in this context, 'fair' means *reasonable*. In other words, the interviewee thinks it is a question that the boss is entitled to ask (presumably because it is relevant to the boss's decision regarding whether to hire the interviewee).

Comment: That's a fair answer.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod - Fair enough for an upvote?  ;)

Comment: Sure. Upvote granted.

Comment: No fair!!!!!!!!